# MPMD parallelization on multiple GPUs with JAX

Tags: python, parallel-processing, jax

I'm writing a parallel tempering program which needs to utilize both automatic differentiation and MPMD parallelization on multiple GPUs (say two). For the former, I have been using JAX and it is a fantastic tool at that. For the latter, I know that JAX supports SPMD parallelization via `pmap`, but I'm not so familiar with whether (and how) MPMD can be achieved in JAX. Could anyone kindly give a hint?